# Delete current preference screen and go back to main preference screen

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a PreferenceActivity launched where I add some preference screens programmatically. So I have a list with my preference screens.

Example:

- Toto
- Titi
- Tata

So I iterate and call a function (`Board` is a custom object):

```
private PreferenceScreen CreatePreferenceScreen(Board b) {
    PreferenceScreen p = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
    p.setPersistent(true);
    p.setKey("preferenceScreen_" + b.getId());

    PreferenceCategory general = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    general.setTitle("General");
    p.addPreference(general);

    Preference delete = new Preference(this);
    delete.setTitle("delete");
    final PreferenceScreen pFinal = p;
    delete.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
            String delId = board.getId();
            PreferenceCategory themes = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("themes");
            PreferenceScreen screen =(PreferenceScreen)findPreference("preferenceScreen_" + delId); 
            themes.removePreference(screen);
            /*GO BACK TO PREFERENCEACTIVITY HERE OR KILL THIS SCREEN*/
            return true;
        }
    });
    general.addPreference(delete);
    return p;
}
```

If I click on toto, it opens the preference screen of toto and on this screen I have an option "Delete". If I click on delete it removes this preference screen from the PreferenceActivity (the previous screen) but I'm still on the preference screen toto.

I'd like to go back to the previous screen when I use "Delete".

I can't use `finish()` on my preference screen toto because it exits the app.
If I click on my back button, I go back to the PreferenceActivity (previous screen) and my toto preferences screen has been removed (yata, that function worked!)

Comment: Can you just call onBackPressed() instead.  It should simulate a back button press.

Comment: No, onBackPressed() : "The default implementation finish the activity" so seems to be same as "finish()" :(

Comment: found a solution, edited my post to explain. Thanks Chris for the help .

Comment: I'm happy to hear you solved your problem. I'd recommend that you re-post your solution as an answer to the question. This will allow others in the community to see that this question has a solution already.

Comment: use an Intent to go back to the Preference Screen

Comment: `pFinal.getDialog().dismiss();`
As you've shown, you're doing with your preferences value in an opening dialog (within current activity). I think this is an important point, you should let others know that.
No matter what, your problem is done by yourself. Good job

Comment: You should also consider using Preference Fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user found the solution thanks to the [PreferenceScreen developer documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html).

> When it appears inside another preference hierarchy, it is shown and serves as the gateway to another screen of preferences (either by
>   showing another screen of preferences as a Dialog or via a
>   startActivity(android.content.Intent) from the getIntent()). The
>   children of this PreferenceScreen are NOT shown in the screen that
>   this PreferenceScreen is shown in. Instead, a separate screen will be
>   shown when this preference is clicked.

So replace this:

```
/*GO BACK TO PREFERENCEACTIVITY HERE OR KILL THIS SCREEN*/
```

with this:

```
pFinal.getDialog().dismiss();
```

And it accomplishes the desired job: close the current `preferenceScreen`.